# Spring security 4.0.1 Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-security

This morning i was updating my external libraries of a project. I did this one library at a time, so if something did go wrong i did know what update did cause it.

After i upgraded spring security from 3.2 to 4.0.1.RELEASE the problem started. It seems i cannot submit any form with POST, i always get the error message:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I confirmed that my mappings are correct and accept POST's:

```
2015-07-19 13:03:21,916 [       Thread-1] INFO  n.RequestMappingHandlerMapping            - Mapped "{[/_/account/add],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com..web.AccountController.add(com..web.data.Account,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-07-19 13:03:21,916 [       Thread-1] INFO  n.RequestMappingHandlerMapping            - Mapped "{[/_/account/add],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com..web.AccountController.add(com..web.data.Account,org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

I highly suspect this is related to the upgrade of spring-security from 3.2 to 4.0.1, because everything did work correctly with 3.2.

Anybody know what causes the "Request method 'POST' not supported" when using spring security 4.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, i should have read the "what's new" documentation a bit better. It seems CSRF is enabled by default in spring security 4.0.1. Adding the csrf token as hidden fields does the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: are you sure your issue is solved? I remember having issue with CSRF, it throws 403(access denied not 405) if it is not supplied or the expired one supplied as far as I remember.

Comment: @Aubergine tomcat did show a "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported" over here, maybe it is caused by my configuration. But with the csrf token i did not see the error anymore. Although a bit more puzzling is needed, cause upgrading to 4.0.1 isn't as easy as i thought.

Comment: If you use logback configuration, try setting logger level to debug/trace:

    <logger name="org.springframework.security.web" level="TRACE"/>

This saved me and keeps saving me so much time as Spring can tell you quite a detailed story.

Comment: @Aubergine nice one! Already saved me a lot of time. Found the problem: Request 'GET /_/login/logout' doesn't match 'POST /_/login/logout ; seems you can't use GET anymore to logout likely because of csrf, let's search a bit more how to solve this one.